# Edit file only once and close it

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon

Is there a way to edit a file only once?
So that for example: I open it and its closed (the buffer is killed) after the window closes.
A clarification: I usually have an Emacs deamon running and open windows with `emacsclient -nc [file]`, but I don't want to have every file in my buffer list and I dont want to open a single instance for every file I only edit once.

Any ideas?

Comment: The question seems to suggest that you want to close the window too, not just kill the buffer. AFAIK, neither `C-x #` nor `C-x k` close the window, and just closing the window does not kill the buffer.

Comment: @Drew If `emacsclient` is launched with `-c` (but **not** with `-n`), it will open the file in a new frame. Doing `C-x #` there will kill buffer and close the new frame that launched (and thus the window too).

Comment: @KaushalModi: I see. Is that true for `C-x k` also (I don't think so).

Comment: There is also `C-x 4 0` (`kill-buffer-and-window`), which has the same effect as `C-x k` (`kill-buffer`) in `emacsclient`, but additionally has the desired behaviour under "normal" Emacs operation (for some definition thereof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `emacsclient -nc [file]`, if you remove the `-n` argument and do just `emacsclient -c [file]`, you can quickly close the popped frame and buffer by calling `server-edit`, which is bound to `C-x #` by default.

---

For instance, my workflow for editing crontab files would be:

1. `crone` (aliased to `setenv VISUAL emacsclient && crontab -e` *(tcsh)*) in terminal.
2. Update the crontab
3. `C-x #`

Notice that I choose to not use even the `-c` argument. I like the file to pop up in my one and only emacsclient frame (already open). When I am done editing that file, `C-x #` will save the file (update crontab), kill the buffer, and I will be back to where I was in my emacsclient frame before I called `crone` from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can end the edit session of such files by killing their buffer (e.g. `C-x k RET`).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `M-x delete-frame`. This will close the actual frame.

Comment: But it won't close the buffer, which was the point of the question.